# Initializing an array of objects using .append in swift doesn't work as I expect

Tags: swift, oop, initialization

When initializing an array of objects in Swift (Xcode 15.0.1) all of the objects contained the values of the last object initialized. Using a different way of initializing works, but I can't figure out what the reason is all of het objects seem to be the same.

The definition of my class:

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var naam: String
    var datum: String
    
    override init(){
        naam = ""
        datum = ""
    }
    
    init(_ naam: String, _ datum: String){
        self.naam = naam
        self.datum = datum
    }
}
```

What didn't work:

```
var item = Item()
  
for i in 0...2 {
    item.naam = "naam\(i)"
    item.datum = "datum\(i)"
    items.append(item)
}
        
for i in items {
    print(i.naam, i.datum)
}
```

Result:

```
    naam2 datum2
    naam2 datum2
    naam2 datum2
```

What works:

```
var item = Item()
  
for i in 0...2 {
    item.naam = "naam\(i)"
    item.datum = "datum\(i)"
    items.append(Item("naam\(i)", "datum\(i)"))
}
        
for i in items {
    print(i.naam, i.datum)
}
```

Result:

```
    naam0 datum0
    naam1 datum1
    naam2 datum2
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes#Use-Classes-When-You-Need-to-Control-Identity Side not: Using a struct would have different output. That's the diff between class & structs Here a little test you can run: https://pastebin.com/jGvJ7a4y

Answer (score 0):

It's reference semantic.

When you create an item outside the for loop and then append it directly in the array, you're actually passing a single instance of `Item`, they're pointing at the same address, and you're just replacing their value. You can check it by printing out its memory addresses.

```swift
for i in items {
    print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(i).toOpaque())
}
```

First case (which don't work):

```
0x0000600001615dd0
0x0000600001615dd0
0x0000600001615dd0
```

Second case (which works). You're creating 3 different instances of `Item`, and doing nothing with the `item` instance outer, and it's correct.

```
0x0000600002364b40
0x0000600002364f90
0x00006000023647e0
```

Comment: Thx. Placing "item" inside the loop indeed works. Reminds me a the difference between pointers and references in C.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same under the hood.